# __Proto__ obsolete and getting to the getArea method

Tags: javascript

http://jsbin.com/ifoguf/19/edit

I'm unable to access the get area function of Triangle, and getting a deprecated error.  Google(ed) the Crockford solution to `__Proto__`, but could use help applying it to the jsbin example.

```
    function extend(Child, Parent) {
        var F = function () {};
        F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
        Child.prototype = new F();
        Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
        Child.uber = Parent.prototype;
    }
    function extend2(Child, Parent) {
        var p = Parent.prototype;
        var c = Child.prototype;
        for (var i in p) {
            c[i] = p[i];
        }
        c.uber = p;
    }
    var Shape = function () {};
    var TwoDShape = function () {};
    var Triangle = function (side, height) {
        this.side = side;
        this.height = height;
    };
    // agument prototype of Shape;
    Shape.prototype.name = 'shape';
    Shape.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.name;
    };
    // augment prototype of Triangle;
    Triangle.prototype.name = 'Triangle';
    Triangle.prototype.getArea = function () {
        return this.side * this.height / 2;
    };
    extend2(TwoDShape, Shape);
    extend2(Triangle, TwoDShape);
    var td = new TwoDShape();
    var tri = new Triangle(5, 10);
    alert(tri.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('name'));

   alert(td.name);
   alert(tri.constructor.getArea());
```

Comment: Please remember to include your code directly in the question so that it can be of use to future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf))

```
var prot = Object.getPrototypeOf(tri);
alert(prot.hasOwnProperty('name'));
```

You would also use that to hit the constructor, so `tri.__proto__.constructor` is now `Object.getPrototypeOf(tri).constructor`

Note that this is not backward compatible with IE<9, so you will still have to use the deprecated method for those browsers. John Resig suggested this as a potential "good enough for now" function to address the lack of user agent support for `getPrototypeOf`:

```
if ( typeof Object.getPrototypeOf !== "function" ) {
  if ( typeof "test".__proto__ === "object" ) {
    Object.getPrototypeOf = function(object){
      return object.__proto__;
    };
  } else {
    Object.getPrototypeOf = function(object){
      // May break if the constructor has been tampered with
      return object.constructor.prototype;
    };
  }
}
```

Reference: http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/

I find this to be functional, but perhaps a bit over-blown - this is what I use:

```
function getProto(obj) {
  return (typeof Object.getPrototypeOf !== 'undefined' ? Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) : obj.__proto__);
}
```